# Передается только первый символ в SQL запрос из Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sybase

Возникла необходимость написать скрипт, забирающий из Anywhere SQL базы некоторые данные. Решил делать его на Python. Делаю запрос с переменной, но почему то в запрос передается только первый символ из переменной. То есть если переменная '20', то передает только цифру 2.

```
import sqlanydb
conn = sqlanydb.connect(uid='dba', pwd='sql', host = 'demsrvdent.demos.local:2638')
curs = conn.cursor()
n = '20'
curs.execute("""select surname FROM patients WHERE patient_id = CONVERT (char, ?)""", n)
s = curs.fetchone()
curs.execute("""select firstname FROM patients WHERE patient_id = CONVERT (char, ?)""", n)
f = curs.fetchone()
curs.execute("""select middlename FROM patients WHERE patient_id = CONVERT (char, ?)""", n)
m = curs.fetchone()
print(s, f, m)
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Потому что второй аргумент метода execute должен быть кортеж, а не строка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметры передавайте в коллекции, например в кортеже:

```
n = '20'
curs.execute(sql, (n,))
#                 ^^^^
```

Поэтому, у вас первый символ передавался